# Contribution Test Pages work only for Amount = $1.00

Tags: civicontribute, contribution-page, iats, testing

I hesitated to raise this issue because I've probably made a real rookie mistake somewhere. My Contribution Pages work fine in production mode but the transactions are not recorded in CiviCRM when I use Test Mode.  All my Contribution Pages are affected. I posted an earlier question [Contribution Pages are not working in Test-Drive Mode](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/41830/contribution-pages-are-not-working-in-test-drive-mode) about this when I thought that all Tests were failing.  Here's the screenshot iATS log in CiviCRM [image: iATS log in CiviCRM]

It shows that $1.00 transactions in Test Mode are OK. Test transactions for other amounts are Rejected. What am I missing? Is this a CiviCRM problem or an iATS problem?
(CiviCRM 5.48.0 on WordPress Version 5.9.3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's functioning as it should ->

VISA 4222222222222220 / exp date in future and CVV any 3 digits -> will result in OK for all $amounts

VISA 411111111111111 / exp date in future and CVV any 3 digits -> will produce results based on the $amount

Documentation:
https://content.iatspayments.com/developers-test-credit-card-numbers

PS - and test transactions are hidden from the normal UI. So you will want to Contributions -> Find Contributions and then specifically indicate "Contribution is a Test" -> hit the Yes radio button.

PS2 - alternatively you can set up the iATS test payment processor as it's own payment processor in CiviCRM and then process LIVE with fake VISA. These transactions are easier to find but they do require some ad-hoc clean up.

Comment: Thank you, KarinG, for including the link to the iATS developers guide.